# Python socket ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer vs socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sockets, urllib, errno

I'm having trouble debugging my code because I cannot understand the socket error being raised.
Here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "clickpression.py", line 517, in <module> presser.main()
 File "clickpression.py", line 391, in main
 File "clickpression.py", line 121, in clickpress self.refresh_proxies(country=country)
 File "clickpression.py", line 458, in refresh_proxies self.proxies = self.get_proxies(country=country)
 File "helpers.py", line 72, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "clickpression.py", line 264, in get_proxies self.settings.SUPER_PROXY).read().decode('utf-8')
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open response = self._open(req, data)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 481, in _open '_open', req)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain result = func(*args)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1210, in http_open return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1185, in do_open r = h.getresponse()
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1171, in getresponse response.begin()
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 351, in begin version, status, reason = self._read_status()
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 313, in _read_status line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 374, in readinto return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

According to the `errno` library `Errno 54` is `errno.EXFULL` which in the python 3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/errno.html) is explained as `exchange full`.

To my understanding the `Connection reset by peer` is `Errno 104` i.e `errno.ECONNRESET`.

So what does `errno.EXFULL` mean? and why does socket raise the error with a `connection reset by peer` description instead of `exchange full`. And or how are the two errors `errno.EXFULL` and `errno.ECONNRESET` related?

PS: I [read](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/171) that the `errno 54` might be related to http proxy (I'm using a proxy in my code). If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

> According to the `errno` library `Errno 54` is `errno.EXFULL`

Did you determine that by examining `errno.errorcode[54]`? Anyway - this *`errno` library* might be at fault. You could verify the meaning of an error code on your system by looking into `errno.h`, e. g. with the help of `gcc`:

```
gcc -xc -imacros errno.h -Wp,-P -E <(echo ECONNRESET)
```

Also, the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html) says:

> To translate a numeric error code to an error message, use
>   os.strerror().

<strike>It may well be that error number 54 is `ECONNRESET` on your system, and that `os.strerror(54)` will attest that.</strike>

Now that you have verified that `os.strerror(54)` returns 'Exchange full', I am puzzled why the error number `54` and the error string `Connection reset by peer` do not match. If that happens on a system with `strace` or something similar, I would further check which error is returned by the operating system through use of `strace -e network` on the affected process.

Regarding your question about EXFULL: Its meaning seems somewhat system dependent; e. g. on Linux, EXFULL is returned from only a handful places in the kernel, the only network-related place being in [br_if.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/bridge/br_if.c#L309) concerning network bridges, when no available bridge port number is found (other places are in USB and SCSI drivers).

Comment: you did not answer my question(s)

Comment: Right - instead I showed ways to vet whether your questions are the right ones, since it is highly questionable whether the shown traceback has anything to do with EXFULL.

Comment: on my system os.strerror(54) returns 'Exchange full' and os.strerror(104) is 'connection reset by peer'

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use python to crew coin market on OKEX.com using WebSocket,cause the url is an outer address,i used a vpn service provided by us,but it still can work. here is the code an traceback.

```
from ws4py.client.threadedclient import WebSocketClient


class DummyClient(WebSocketClient):
    def opened(self):
      # self.send("{'event': 'addChannel', 'channel': 'ok_sub_futureusd_btc_ticker_this_week'}") #发送请求数据格式
         # self.send("www.baidu.com")
         self.send("{'event':'addChannel','channel':'ok_sub_spot_bch_btc_ticker'}")
    def closed(self, code, reason=None):
        print("Closed down", code, reason)

#服务器返回消息
    def received_message(self, m):
        print("recv:", m)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        # 服务器连接地址wss://real.okex.com:10440/websocket/okexapi
       # ws = DummyClient('wss://real.okcoin.cn:10440/websocket/okcoinapi', protocols=['chat'])
        ws = DummyClient('wss://real.okex.com:10440/websocket/okexapi', protocols=['chat'])
        ws.connect()
        #ws.send("my test...")
        ws.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ws.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can try this code to your project:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

if it not work,make sure the server open TLSv1 support.